# Creating multiple sub items in an item?

Tags: 2013, custom-list, custom-form, list-item

Using a SharePoint 2013 environment.

Here's the example. A party request form. You have all the standard fields.
Name, location, date, contact, guest count, etc.

My question is when in this circumstance if you would have limit of 15 guest but can put in a food preference for each one. Where it would look like a table/list with guest, entre, side, allergies, dessert, drink.

Is there a better way than adding 15 columns of each field?

This needs to be a single form submission. Cannot have a separate step entering in all the guest dining data into a separate list.

Comment: You can use multiple lines of text field to add such large information.

Comment: @sharepoint_geek That does not answer the question or help. Each needs to be their own item for easy management.